# How to route everything to default controller in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a website http://example.com built using codeigniter 2. the default controller is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "domain";
```

If I try to access pageX, the link should be `http://example.com/en/domain/view/pageX`.
I want to allow the visitor of the website to access this page by typing

```
http://example.com/pageX
```

I have tried

```
$route['(:any)'] = "view/$1"; ==> it gives 404 Page Not Found
$route['(:any)'] = "domain/view/$1"; ==> it redirects to homepage with link shown as http://example.com/en/pageX
$route['(:any)'] = "en/domain/view/$1"; ==> it gives 404 Page Not Found
```

but non of them worked for me.

**EDIT**

by adding this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'domain/view/$1';  
$route['en/blog']   =  'domain/view/blog';
```

`example.com/blog` will work fine
but I need it to be more general to cover all pages except admin page, something like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'domain/view/$1';  
$route['^(?!admin).*']   =  'domain/view/$o';
//The above routes will show the home page only for whatever i try!!
```

What is the route that i have to add to `routes.php`?

Answer (score 0):

`$route['default_controller']` is invoked if there is no URI present.  Use `$route['404_override']` for a full "catch all."

To get your routing pattern working, try this:

```
$route['[^/]*/(.*)'] = 'en/domain/view/$1';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,,, but this didn't work! i am trying to use http://example.com/PageX to route to http://example.com/en/domain/view/PageX .... so the regular expression you have provided doesn't match my input... am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed my problem by doing this

```
$route['^[a-z]+$'] = 'domain/view/$1';
$route['([a-z]{2})/([a-z_]{1,50})'] = 'domain/view/$2';
```